# theorem for free: relation cartesian product

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

I am digging through a paper [Theorems for free](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Edreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf) and a bit confused on the source of some conjectures (page 5):

[image: https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf]

Is it an axiom or it can be implied from some other axioms?

**UPD**

Question is about Cartesian product definition for relations. Is it an axiom or it can be derived from relation/Cartesian production definition?

**UPD2**

To expand on my source of confusion.

I have tried to derive this definition, but it differs from the one given in the paper.
$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$

Then we have from the paper definitions for $\mc A$ and $\mc B$:
$$\mc A: A \iff A'$$
$$\mc B: B \iff B'$$

from Cartesian product definition

$$(X, Y) \in \mc A \times \mc B$$

$X$ and $Y$ are values from corresponding relations $\mc A$ and $\mc B$ and it is possible to expand these values:

$$X \in \mc A, X = (x, x'), \ x \in A,\ x' \in A'$$
$$Y \in \mc B, Y = (y, y'), \ y \in B,\ y' \in B'$$

and then it appears:

$$((x, x'), (y, y')) \in \mc A \times \mc B$$

Tuple type is different from the paper one.

$$((A, A'), (B, B'))\ my\ type$$
$$((A, B), (A', B'))\ paper\ type$$

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like a definition of a product of relations

Comment: @uniquesolution, how can this definition be derived?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
$\mc A\times\mc B$ is not the cartesian product of $\mc A$ and $\mc B$ as sets, but it is a new definition. In fact, it is the cartesian product in the category of relations.

For example (there may be other choices of morphisms), the objects are relations, and a morphism $f : \mc A\to\mc B$ is a pair $(f_1, f_2)$ where $f_1 : A\to B$, $f_2 : A'\to B'$ such that
$$x\mc A y\implies(f_1 x)\mc B (f_2 y).$$

Then you can check that $\mc A\times \mc B$ as given above satisfies the universal property of the product where

$$\hat\pi_1 : \mc A\times\mc B\to \mc A\\\hat\pi_2 :\mc A\times\mc B\to B$$ are given by
$$(\pi_1 : A\times B\to A,\pi_1':A'\times B'\to A')\\
(\pi_2 : A\times B\to B,\pi_2':A'\times B'\to B'),$$
and given
$$f : \mc C\to \mc A\qquad g :\mc C\to\mc B,$$
we obtain
$$\langle f,g\rangle :\mc C\to\mc A\times\mc B$$
by the pair $(f_1\times g_1, f_2\times g_2)$, where notice this time the product of functions is taken in the category of sets.

Comment: thanks! now I need to dig into category theory to verify your answer :)

Comment: @Couchy It is not the category-theoretic product in the category of relations. In fact, the product in the category of relations is the disjoint union.

Comment: @ZhenLin I mean the category of relations where objects are triples $(A,B,\mathcal R)$, with $\mathcal R$ a relation between $A$ and $B$, not sets.

Answer (score 1):

It is a definition. The statement about a product of functions follows from the definition, since if $a,b$ are functions then $((x, y), (x', y')) \in a \times b$ iff $(x, x')\in a, (y, y')\in b$ iff $x' = ax, y' = ay$. Therefore $a\times b$ is a function, as every $(x,y)$ has a unique $(x', y')$ (this is $(ax, ay)$) such that $((x, y), (x', y'))\in a\times b$, and by definition $(a\times b)(x, y) = (ax, ay)$.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I am mostly confused about first part where Cartesian product is defined. It is a convenient axiom or it is implied from Cartesian product/relation definitions?

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Are you asking why the definition of the product of relations coincides with their Cartesian product as sets? If so, it doesn't, as $((x, y), (x', y'))\in A \times B$ (where this is their Cartesian product) iff $(x,y)\in A$ and $(x', y')\in B$.

Comment: Not sure what you reference as `their Cartesian product`. Question can be formulated as "How to derive cartesian product of two relations"

Comment: You don't derive a definition. Definitions tell you what some notion means. The quote from the original paper is telling you what the Cartesian product of relations is. In particular, it is _not_ their Cartesian product as sets.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko the product defined in your post is not the Cartesian product of the relations (as sets).